# What are the advantages and disadvantages of package declarations?

Tags: python, java, modules

Java-family languages often use a `package` declaration at the top of a source file, to group source files into modules/packages independently of their file system layout. Python, however, uses the file system layout to infer what files are in a module. What are the pros and cons of these options?

Answer (score 6):

Disadvantage:

- If you know where the source root is, this is a redundant information, while users will still have to fill it in every time they write a file.
- Moving a file from one package to another requires modifying the file itself, which can cause unnecessary diff in source control (e.g. Git).
- Cannot paste such a file directly from web to a local project, because one needs to change the package declaration. However, this is handled well in modern tools like IntelliJ.

Advantage:

- Whenever you find a Java file, you may use this declaration to find the source root, and then find the other files. This is good for making clever IDEs and editors.
- For beginners, it is clear that where should this file be located in.
- If we see an unimported symbol in a file, we may immediately know that it should be from the same package as declared at the top of the file, without looking at any other file. This improves the information locality in the compiler.

Comment: The last point in advantages doesn't require you package declaration. If your language has packages implicitly from the folder hierarchy you can still have this feature.

Comment: @Aiono but implicit imports from the same package will not be added automatically

Comment: I don't understand, if you have a symbol in the same package you can use it without specifying an import just like you would do with package declarations.

Comment: @Aiono I'm confused. Isn't the question about the advantages and disadvantages of explicit package declarations? It didn't mention it anyway.